# how to update routing tables so that vpn is avoided

Tags: linux, networking, routing

This is probably too trivial question, but I read a lot of pages and still cannot find info how to do basic stuff with routing.

Background info: our company uses obsoleted vpn service(snx), does man-in-the-middle on employees, uses self-singned certificate only and probably more ridiculous stuff, which in the end means, that when I'm logged into company vpn, most of URLs keeps complaining about certificates plus company probably does something fishy, which causes very frequent communication failures.

What I need to do: update routing tables, so that only specified IPs are routed through vpn.

Before I start vpn, routing table look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

after I start vpn, it's turned into this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         192.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 tunsnx
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
A.B.C.D          0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tunsnx
64.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 tunsnx
...
shortened a lot
...
128.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         128.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 tunsnx
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

I tried to debug it using youtube (and help here on forum). So when I do:

```
ip route get 172.217.23.238
```

the response is:

172.217.23.238 dev tunsnx src A.B.C.X uid 1001
cache

which does not appear anywhere in list, but the A.B.C part matches rule with hostname flag.

And here I'm loosing it. I don't understand, what forces youtube to be routed into vpn. Flag UH, as I understand it, should route only specific address mentioned in that rule, so since A.B.C.X isn't A.B.C.D, I'd guess, that this rule wasn't used. If it wasn't used, and nothing else is present in route table, then it must be default gateway rule. Luckily, we have two. One with zeroes, one with work "default". No idea which should be used preferrably, but I'd go with one marked with flag G, which isn't our vpn tunsnx nic.

So I wanted to kill the one-of-the-default gateway, the one related to tunsnx nic:

```
sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0
```

and the default gateway on wlp0s20f3 was deleted instead, leaving system in reboot-ready state, with `route` hangs after printed only one line.

yes and I should probably say, that I had to turn off systemd-resolved, as I was unable to configure it to work with snx.

I'm probably missing some very trivial piece of information, which blocks me from understanding what is happening/why/and how to avoid that tunsnx for most of traffic. Can someone help (link to in-depth resources where this is really explained in readable fashion is welcome as well).

UPDATE: If I just delete all routes related to tunsnx nic[1], I end up in dysfunctional state. While routing table look exactly like before snx was started, nothing is reachable until I turn of the snx. Can that somehow be related to 2 default routes?

UPDATE2: I tried:

- drop just tunsnx default gateway and keep other untouched —> will block all traffic.
- drop just tunsnx default gateway and recreate it with bigger metric so that it is not used —> will block all traffic
- after dropping all tunsnx routes, I also dropped normal default gateway and recreated it to find out if it does not help, and it doesn't.

UPDATE 3: after starting vpn, I removed all tunsnx rules and run following commands as requested to find out, if snx still somehow interferes:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -I any
tcpdump: tunsnx: That device doesn't support monitor mode
```

and the same thing for wifi nic:

```
sudo  tcpdump -n -I wlp0s20f3
tcpdump: tunsnx: That device doesn't support monitor mode
```

please notice, that even that we asked for wlp0s20f3, the complain is still about tunsnx we did not ask about.

[1]  `route -n | grep tunsnx | sed "s/^\([0-9.]*\) *\([0-9.]*\) *\([0-9.]*\) .*/sudo route del -net \1 gw \2 netmask \3;/" | tr -d "\n" ;echo`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you appear to be experiencing is that the VPN is overriding your default route by having a number of more specific  subnets.

The solution is to remove all the routes going through tunsnx and to add anew roytes for tunsnx which only cover the IP ranges which are used by hosts of interest at your place of work.  (This is likely limited to a subnet of IP addresses they use as well as 10.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 and 172.16.0.0/12 - being space used by NAT and not on tbe public Internet anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'd like to do, thanks for list of IPs. Can you also advice about two default gateway and why is (probably) the one without G flag used in preference?

Comment: There is they system default gateway (the second one in your second route table) - this has a Metric of "600", meaning the first default gateway (via the VPN) is preferred because it has a lower metric.

Comment: I don't think the "G" (which stands for gateway) is actually used to determine the route, although its probably used to determine how the route is processed.

Comment: Re your update - can you post a list of your routes before and after you delete the tunsnx ones.  You need to delete the tunsnx default route as well.

Comment: I really not sure if I can, I know it's just IPs, but unless you really need it, I'd like to avoid that. I can guarantee you though, that routing table is the same: 1. `route -n > /tmp/a` 2. start vpn, delete tunsnx using `route -n | grep tunsnx | sed "s/^\([0-9.]*\) *\([0-9.]*\) *\([0-9.]*\) .*/-net \1 gw \2 netmask \3/"  | while read J; do sudo route del $J;done` 3. `route -n >/tmp/b` 4. do diff and there is NO difference. Except for dysfunctional network. So the listing looks as in original question, "before I start vpn"

Comment: ...namely there isn't ANY tunsnx rule, and there is default gateway `0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3`

Comment: Are you sure that the VPN is not injecting iptables / firewall rules?  After removing the iptables rules but with TunSNX stuff still running, what does tcpdump show (eg "tcpdump -n -I any"  and tcpdump -n -Iwlp0s20f3" while trying to access stuff?

Comment: Thanks for all your effort to help. I've very unsure; I'm total beginner and I didn't see this explained anywhere. So it's rather probable, that something like this must be happening. But I have no idea how I can influence it. Updating question with your commands results

Comment: Does "iptables -vnL" show any firewall rules only when the vpn is up?

Comment: I don't understand iptables sufficiently, but diff of before/after vpn started is minimal, only 2 differences, in number of packets and bytes on lines like this: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 830K packets, 1109M bytes)` So I'd think there isn't any such rules we're looking for.

Comment: Then its not an iptables/firewall thing. - at least not an obvious thing.